# swift WebView open unwanted browser after navigation buttons

Tags: ios, swift, browser, webview, navigation

My `webview` opens a webpage and works well except when it randomly opens the page in the browser after `goBack` or `goForward` methods.
I've searched for solutions but didn't find anything about preventing the browser from opening.

```
@IBAction func didClickNextBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if webView.canGoForward {
        webView.goForward()
    }
}
```

This issue happens when I push this buttons instantly (or the same happens when the internet connection off and trying to go back or forward )
I tried to disable the buttons while it's loading the page but that not helped and that way feel wrong

Comment: So you are saying that it opens the link in Safari when you click the next button?  Always, or only sometimes?

Comment: Only sometimes it's happens the most when I push the buttons instantly and I tried to disconnect the internet while it's loading and the results (If the page don't loaded or the internet disconnected) it's happen on every push of this methods

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement `func webView(WKWebView, decidePolicyFor: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)` from `WKNavigationDelegate`, and print all `navigationAction`.

If some wired urls lead this issues, just call `decisionHandler(.cancel)` within this method to block them.